# Azure Linux WebApp netcore logging to disk worked example

Tags: linux, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

Can someone provide a worked example of how to log to disk on a linux azure webapp running a simple console webapi project.

I want to log the following to disk.

Console,Debug,ILogger

I cannot find any examples showing what is required in CreateHostBuilder, appsettings.json and in the azure blade setup.

Every thing I had read seems to be for Windows and does not work for Linux.

I have tried the following:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureLogging(logging => logging.AddAzureWebAppDiagnostics())
        .ConfigureServices(serviceCollection => serviceCollection
            .Configure<AzureFileLoggerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.FileName = "azure-diagnostics-";
                options.FileSizeLimit = 50 * 1024;
                options.RetainedFileCountLimit = 5;
            })
            .Configure<AzureBlobLoggerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.BlobName = "log.txt";
            }))
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => { webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>(); });
```

appsettings.json
Is FilePath needed? What is the path format?

{

```
  "Logging": {
    "FilePath": "LogFiles",
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
```

site/diagnostics/settings.json
Does this override appsettings.json? Vice versa? What is what?

```
"AzureDriveEnabled":false,
"AzureDriveTraceLevel":"Verbose",
"AzureTableEnabled":false,
"AzureTableTraceLevel":"Error",
"AzureBlobEnabled":true,
"AzureBlobTraceLevel":"Verbose"
}
```

[image]

However when I check my FTP log location I only ever see the following regarding docker deployments and other stuff that is not useful.

[image]

I am happy to use serilog or literally anything that works. I currently cannot even view the logs via the log stream on the azure app blade.

Comment: try updating. It will work

Comment: Updating what? I have deployed, restarted etc, no logs show anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

We use nlog for apps running on linux containers. Hope this will help to you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      autoReload="true"
      internalLogLevel="Info"
      internalLogFile="/fluentd/etc/log/internal/internal-nlog.log">

  <variable name="logFolderName" value="log" />
  <variable name="logBaseDirectory" value="/fluentd/etc/" />
  <variable name="logDirectory" value="${logBaseDirectory}${logFolderName}"/>
  <variable name="appname" value="Docker utility"/>

  <!-- enable asp.net core layout renderers -->
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Web.AspNetCore"/>
  </extensions>

  <!-- the targets to write to -->
  <targets>
    <!-- for dev debug purposes -->
    <target xsi:type="ColoredConsole" name="console" />
    <!-- write to file -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="allData" fileName="${logDirectory}/all/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}" />
    <!-- another file log. Uses some ASP.NET core renderers -->
    <target xsi:type="File" name="ownData" fileName="${logDirectory}/info/${shortdate}.log" layout="${longdate}|${event-properties:item=EventId_Id}|${uppercase:${level}}|${logger}|${message} ${exception:format=tostring}|url: ${aspnet-request-url}|action: ${aspnet-mvc-action}" />
  </targets>

  <!-- rules to map from logger name to target -->
  <rules>
    <!--All logs, including from Microsoft-->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="allData" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="console" />
    <!--Skip non-critical Microsoft logs and so log only own logs-->
    <logger name="Microsoft.*" maxlevel="Info" final="true" />
    <!-- BlackHole without writeTo -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="ownData" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Then configure nlog in Program.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using NLog.Web;
using System;

var logger = NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config").GetCurrentClassLogger();
try
{
    logger.Debug("init main");
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                .ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                {
                    serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
                })
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
            })
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Trace);
            })
            .UseNLog()
            .Build()
            .Run();
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    //NLog: catch setup errors
    logger.Error(exception, "Stopped program because of exception");
    throw;
}
finally
{
    // Ensure to flush and stop internal timers/threads before application-exit (Avoid segmentation fault on Linux)
    NLog.LogManager.Shutdown();
}
```

[nlog documentation](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial)

results will be like this

```
2021-07-08 14:09:52.6206||DEBUG| test.Api.Program|init main
```

Answer (score 0):

**~QUICK NOTE~**

**Edit the config appsettings via Powershell. The command syntax is:**

```
az webapp config appsettings delete | list | set <--OPTIONS> [--OPTIONS]
```

**This will also let you see the current values of any options with 'list'. Learn more [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest)**

---

---

That said, no matter how you configure the app, if, as you said, you cannot pull up a Linux command line and access your system, that should be your main concern. You can find out more with a shell than your log files could possibly tell you. Real time environment values access alone is invaluable.

On windows, in 2021, a bash instance (the real deal running atop a REAL Linux kernel) is free and takes about 1 and a half minutes plus  download time to install. I'm talking about Microsoft's [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about). If you are a developer working in windows, you are going to need this anyway. Imo, it is one of the best development tools that MS offers (While were on the subject, windows also just released a beta for their new 'Terminal' app. It lets you access wsl,CMD, and Powershell, all from one place. Like an IDE shell.)

All of your system logs are written to `/var/log/...` inside your Linux OS. If you enter the command:

```
cd /var/log/ && la
```

This will let you see them. `la` is like `ls` but it lets you see the hidden ".files" as well. You can use that inside your home folder to see the `.config` directory, with configurations for various apps.

**~ENVIRONMENT-RELATED-CONTEXT~**

Instead of just giving commands, as we're dealing with Linux,I will try to add some more useful context to go along with the commands. This will be much more help in the long run, because, no matter what you find out as a result, you're guaranteed to run into an issue or two that wasn't covered. That is just how Linux works. It requires good troubleshooting technique and at least a partial / high-level understanding as to how the system functions.

On a standard Linux console (at least the bash variety, and most likely Zsh as well) there is a concept known as **redirection** which will let you write *anything* that is headed for STDOUT (console) to a file instead. In fact, there are multiple forms of redirection. I will mention a few.

**~SHELL COMMANDS SUITED TO YOUR GOAL~**

First of all, you can move output from STDOUT to a file of your choosing. If this file doesn't exist yet, it will be created in the current directory. The syntax for using the redirection operator(s) is as follows.

*This will overwrite* `file` *with the output from* `command-with-output`:

```
$ command-with-output > file
```

..and this will append `file-with-output` to any content that is already on `file`:

```
$ command-with-output >> file
```

For example,to search the logs for a file named 'oak.log', and then write it's contents of path `~/mylogs/myaptlog.log.01`, use:

```
$ cat /var/log/apt/* | grep 'oak.log' >> ~/mylogs/myaptlog.log.01
```

The downside is that now your output is headed for a file, so you wont be able to see it at stdout console.

To solve this issue, we have the `tee` command. This let's you break the flow of your IO data into two seperate streams (hence the name tee). By default, one writes to a specified file, and the other goes to the console. However, this can be changed with --flags. For example, you could write to multiple files or pipe the stdout into yet another pipe | command.

the syntax for `tee` is:

```
$ some-command | tee -a some-file
```

The `-a` is for append. This lets you write to the end of a file. If it is missing and the file already exists, it will be overwritten.

To find out more about `tee` or any linux command, just type

```
$ man <command>
```

this will pull up the docs for that command. `man` is a VERY valuable resource. There are times when I have a full monitor dedicated to running 3-4 separate instances of `man` for different commands. That is never the plan; it is just extremely convenient.

Quick note: For any command, if you get an error mentioning either 'root' or 'permissions', prepend the command listed before the error message with the word `sudo`.

**~~ HELPFUL-TOOLS ~~**

Now that the context is out of the way, I can tell you that if you are wanting to write your files to a location outside the container (so that they persist after the container is destroyed) this can be done fairly easily either via a messaging client or from Linux itself with a few commands.

For the latter method, you will need something like `openssh-server` on the remote (which you already have according to the pic in your question) for ensuring that the data gets to an external IP safely. The installation method depends on the distro that you are running, but your package managers are almost always your best option.

The command that you will actually use is called `sftp`, but it depends on ssh for it's connection (that is what the h stands for), so it requires openssh-client (which comes w/ most Linux versions), and also some sort of ssh server application at the other end.

`sftp` is a built-in command, as are all the commands I have mentioned so far. This means that you can use the:

```
man sftp
```

command to quickly master the options / syntax.

In order to use sftp, you may also need to configure your firewall settings. In this case, the app for the job is ufw.  As I just had to add rules to my own system yesterday, the syntax is fresh for me. You have a couple of choices to make you can just add the rule

```
ufw allow 22/sftp
```

or you can specify the endpoints:

```
ufw allow out proto sftp from <ip address> to <ip address>
```

If you are on windows, you will benefit from running **WSL 2.** It is a free Windows app, from Microsoft, that gives you an actual running Linux Kernel that runs *inside* Windows.

**~~ SUMMARY ~~**
In your question you say:

Looking more closely at your question, You already have much (most?) of this solution completed for you. You do have a shell access, ssh-server, and even sftp **already**. All you need to do is use powershell or a WSL 2 shell (You have many to choose from and can have many installed at once.) From WSL 2, the command is ssh @ and give password when prompted, and you're in. simple as that.

That said, it gets simpler. I already gave you the location of the OS system logs (which are VITAL for any serious debug session on Linux, imo.) **Just use sftp.** An acceptable answer is listed in the question. If you prune them they'll grow back.

Comment: I'm using a net core Linux Web app not a server so I can't actually log into a terminal that I know of?

Comment: If you are running the app on a remote Linux environment somewhere, you need only put a bash script in with, and call it from, your code. I'm not familiar with the api, but I bet a million dollars that there is a method in there for calling bash scripts. It's probably exec, or something similar. Bash scripting is simple enough that you don't need to have ever done it before in order to write a simple script. You just write the commands that I've listed, line by line, and make sure that the top line says `#!/bin/bash`.  I'll do some research and get back to you.

Comment: I've never used Azure, but if it's anything like aws, (i.e. your app runs in a Linux container) ssh is easy, and gives you FULL access to your remote OS. I would try to pull up the tty shell. Also, if you're your development computer is windows, you can download wsl2 for free. It gives you a bash shell in Windows, which would make it easier to run commands remotely via SSH. I would set that up whether or not you choose to use my answer. It will make things a lot easier on you in the future.

Comment: [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-linux-open-ssh-session) may help.

Comment: @rolls Updated answer. Added 1st, 2nd, and last sections, and structured the entire answer into subsections for readability. If you cannot get it with this, then I don't know what else to say. With the info above, I could almost just do it for you. XD

Comment: Your answer is not portable. I need it to work entirely from C# so that I can deploy it to windows or linux without requiring any access to shell or ssh which is a security hole. I need to be able to have logging working from first launch of the server without any manual steps. I understand how to use bash and linux but that is not what I am asking. I'm asking how to setup the aspnet logging in C# to work on linux. aspnet netcore is cross platform, so I need a cross platform solution. nlog below is an example of what I am asking. I have not yet have time to try it out however.